# Android google map api getlastlocation() always return null

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

I do need to get the user location continuously; therefore, I use getlastlocation() to get current location of the user. However, it always returns null.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
    ,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    protected double x, y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if(mGoogleApiClient == null){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}

protected void onStart(){
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {

    if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
    else {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLastLocation != null){
            x = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            y = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        else{
            Log.e("error", "null");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng gpsLocation = new LatLng(x, y);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gpsLocation).title("Here"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(gpsLocation));
}
```

`Log.e("error", "null")` always executes, meaning getlastlocation() always returns null. In AndroidManifest, I have state enough permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I searched for similar posts on stackOverflow, and they give some reason (e.g: GPS is not open), but none of them can apply in my cases.

Comment: Have you seen if you are getting into onConnectionFailed()?

Comment: Just check, I didn't enter onConnectionFailed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created `LocationRequest` and requested for location update using `requestLocationUpdates`?

You need to create `LocationRequest` like below code.

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

protected void createLocationRequest() {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

}
```

And using `LocationRequest`, you need to call `requestLocationUpdates` of `FusedLocationApi` like below code.

```
protected void startLocationUpdates(){
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest,this);
}
```

After that you will get location in `getlastlocation()` method of `FusedLocationApi`.

Also you should call `removeLocationUpdates`, when it's not required.

```
 protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks faithfully for your comment. But still return null after using requestLocationUpdates before getlastlocation()  :(.